# How do you make questions about elements in a subordinate clause?

Tags: grammar

I am forming the open interrogative from the following declaratives, replacing the italicized phrases with a corresponding interrogative phrase such as who, what etc.

> "He thinks they'll appoint *someone*."
> "You think *someone* has the most influence with their people."

Does it follow the same way for a normal main clause?
like "They'll appoint *someone*" -> "Who will they appoint?"
So the first example sentence will be changed to "Who does he thinks they'll appoint?" Is it right?

Comment: You seem to be trying to do something that only people learning English as a foreign language would understand, never mind do (grammarians excepted). I do not think you are on the right site. Try [ell.se].

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Who does he think they'll appoint?" is exactly right. Similarly, "Who do you think has the most influence with their people?"